# Finding the region in which the complex series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^n + \left(\frac{z}{b}\right)^n\right)$ for $a,b\neq0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, power-series

I have the trouble with the complex series $S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^n + \left(\frac{z}{b}\right)^n\right)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^\times$, that I am unsure how to manipulate the summand algebraic to $w^n$ for some $w$. Here is what I have done so far: $\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^n + \left(\frac{z}{b}\right)^n = \frac{(ab)^n + z^{2n}}{(bz)^n} = \frac{(ab)^n(\overline{bz})^n + z^{2n}(\overline{bz})^n}{|bz|^n} = \frac{|b|^n(a\overline{z})^n + (z\overline{b})^n|z|^n}{|bz|^n}$. But I have no clue how to continue beyond this point.

Edit: We are trying to find the largest region in which the series $S$ converges.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to find a closed-form expression for that infinite sum? Are you trying to determine a radius of convergence of some kind (or rather, a domain of convergence, because it will likely be an annulus)? Etc.

Comment: @march Argh, my bad! What I was going to write was: Find the largest region in which the given series converges.

Comment: You don't have to combine the two terms. The series converges iff both $|a/z|$ and $|z/b|$ are less than one, which means $|a|<|z|<|b|$.

Comment: @TravorLZH It occurred to me only just now, how do we know that the iff condition holds? I do understand that if we can impose conditions on the individual terms of the sum, then we know when the whole sum converges. But what about the reverse direction?